# Progress Dialogue Not Showing On AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am using an AsyncTask To show progress dialogue, the code is running as expected but the progress dialogue is still not showing up. Everything inside doInBackground is executing perfectly. I'm unable to understand what is causing this.

Async Task ->

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{


    ProgressDialog pd;
    Context context;
    PyObject object;
    String str;

    MyAsyncTask(Context contexted) {
        this.context = contexted;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pd.setMessage("This May Take Some Time");
        pd.setTitle("Loading Tweet Engine");
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();

        super.onPreExecute();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String og = strings[0];
        if(!Python.isStarted()){
            Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(context));
            Python py = Python.getInstance();
            PyObject pyf = py.getModule("myscript");
            object = pyf.callAttr("get_tweets",og);
        }
        else {
            Python py = Python.getInstance();
            PyObject pyf = py.getModule("myscript");
            object = pyf.callAttr("get_tweets",og);
        }

        return object.toString();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        pd.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

And it is called by ->

```
String returnlist = new MyAsyncTask(this).execute(tempvalued).get();
```

Comment: remove `get()` use callbacks instead

Comment: What context are you using? MyAsyncTask(Context contexted) should have context from Activity or View that will show that dialog. If you use ApplicationContext or BaseContext, dialog won't show...

Comment: new MyAsyncTask(this) --> is `this` activity context?

Comment: @Raghunandan Can you show an example

Comment: @Kubik I Think the problem is wwith my context because Im using just a single activity , but still when i pass getApplicationContext() or getBaseContext() it force closes , but when I use MainActivity.this the program gets executed but the progress bar is still not shown

Comment: @AjinkyaPingale there many examples available online. https://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-using-fragment-as-a-container-for-asynctask/